# Combine LINQ and Foreach which in turn creates another list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have the following piece of code which I am trying to improve:

```
var ApprovedAllowancesProductIds = from item in ApprovedAllowancesListFiltered select item.ProductId; //(1)

List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
List<string> partitionProductKeys = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in ApprovedAllowancesProductIds)   //(2)
{
    string[] partitionKey = new string[] { CountryCD, item.ToString() };
    string PartitionKey = partitionKey.ConcatenatedStringWithPipeSeparator();
    partitionProductKeys.Add(PartitionKey);
}

var resultProduct = await _tableStorageService.FetchDataByMultiplePartitionKey<Product>(partitionProductKeys, QueryComparisonEnums.Equal);
productList.Add((Product)resultProduct);
```

For better performance I want to combine the functionality of (2) i.e., the entire foreach loop in (1). I saw some example as: [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031956/combine-foreach-with-linq) and [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760482/combine-foreach-loop-and-linq-query-into-single-linq-query) but they don't serve my purpose so please don't mark this as duplicate.

Comment: You can use linq to reduce your code but performance is another topic

Answer (score 2):

you could combine with `Select`

```
var partitionProductKeys = ApprovedAllowancesProductIds
    .Select(item => 
    {
        string[] partitionKey = new string[] { CountryCD, item.ToString() };
        return partitionKey.ConcatenatedStringWithPipeSeparator();
    })
    .ToList();
```

you could apply the same concept with `ApprovedAllowancesListFiltered`  if you want to merge the fist line as well with this code.

Comment: Thanks vivek for quick response. However, Can we also do it while creating the ApprovedAllowancesProductIds i.e., at line var ApprovedAllowancesProductIds = from item in ApprovedAllowancesListFiltered select item.ProductId; ??.  I would save me an additional variable cost.

Comment: var ApprovedAllowancesProductIds = from item in ApprovedAllowancesListFiltered
                                               select item.ProductId.ToString()
                                               .ToList().Select(item =>
                                               {
                                                   string[] partitionKey = new string[] { CountryCD, item.ToString() };
                                                   return partitionKey.ConcatenatedStringWithPipeSeparator();
                                               }).ToList();

Comment: @Abhishek_Singh_Rana yes yo can, just give it a try.I have provided the direction

Comment: Thanks :)..I will update the final answer when I test :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the outer list completely and loop on the objects instead of the property ProductId of the objects:

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
List<string> partitionProductKeys = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in ApprovedAllowancesListFiltered)
{
    string[] partitionKey = new string[] { CountryCD, item.ProductId.ToString() };
    string PartitionKey = partitionKey.ConcatenatedStringWithPipeSeparator();
    partitionProductKeys.Add(PartitionKey);
}
var resultProduct = await _tableStorageService.FetchDataByMultiplePartitionKey<Product>(partitionProductKeys, QueryComparisonEnums.Equal);
productList.Add((Product)resultProduct);
```

I hope this helps.